# What is the pros and cons of buying domain and webhosting space in different providers?

Tags: dns, cross-domain, web-hosting, server

For example,

Buying domain in godaddy.com and buying wehosting in hostgator.in. Is there any advantages and disadvantages please discuss about this.

I searched in internet I didn't get any clarifications regarding this also there is no much details found about this.

Anyone experienced very bad or too good please share with me.

Answer (score 1):

From experience in web hosting there is no real disadvantage in this set-up.

I personally have a domain bought from GoDaddy and have a web-server hosted on 1and1 with no issues.  The set-up may be a little more complicated due to pointing the domain to the dns etc but other than that there shouldn't be anything else to cause problems.